# Excel : Values without duplicates

Tags: excel, list, duplicates, formula

I have a list of names in one column with duplicates.
I would like in another column to get all the names without duplicates.
I don't want to use VBA and after hours of searching, I can't find what formula I should use.

Here is what I am trying to do:

List of names:
[image: List of names]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The duplicates can't be removed from the first list as you can have multiple times the same person do different tasks. I also want it to be a formula as I want it to be automatic and not have to filter the list myself.

Comment: Use advance filter to extract unique values only.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Harun24HR, but if someone then adds a new name to the list, will it automatically update the second list ? Let's say there is only multiple A and B, if someone adds C will the second list add C ?

Comment: Resume the list names with a Pivot Table. The only thing you have to do is refreshing with 1 single click the Pivot Table if a new name is added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best option i've found for you without using vba:

https://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/30/how-to-extract-a-unique-list-and-the-duplicates-in-excel-from-one-column/#uniquedistinct

Comment: =IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$B$11;MATCH(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($E$2:E2;$B$3:$B$11)=0;COUNTIF($B$3:$B$11;"<"&$B$3:$B$11);"");1);COUNTIF($B$3:$B$11;"<"&$B$3:$B$11);0));"").

This worked for me, the formula can be copied down and the iferror makes for formula cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

In Data menu of ms excel exist a option with name "RemoveDuplicateData". Check this option.
[image: RemoveDuplicateData]

please check this options:
[image: excelconditionalformatting]

Comment: OP writes in comments: *The duplicates can't be removed from the first list as you can have multiple times the same person do different tasks*

Comment: Also this gives completly wrong output. If you use this all names will be outputed once. OP want's names that only exist once in the list. Remove Duplicates is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if()` and `countif()`.
In `B1` place this formula

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1,"Duplicate","Unique")
```

And if you fill this in your table you end up with:

[image]

Then you just filter the table on "Unique".

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it well enough. Let's say the column has : A B A C D F G B. In a second column, I want the values A B C D F G. Then if someones adds X to the first column, I want X to appear in the second column as well.

Comment: @The_Badger_Novice I'm not sure that works without VBA. Why don't you want to use VBA?

Comment: Good question, it was specified to me to not use VBA. I agree that it would be easy to do otherwise, i'm just trying to find a way to do it without. It would be a formula that I put in the whole of my second column that shows nothing if there isn't a value and then when a new value is added to the first column the second column updates.

Comment: Well the formula can be made to not show anything if it's unique, or the other way around. Regarding VBA it can be a UDF that acts as a formula but is VBA.